# Can't update Centos 6 kernel with yum, uname -r is still showing the old version

Tags: kernel, centos, rpm, yum, centos6

I sended those commands:

```
# yum install kernel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosr3.centos.org
 * extras: centosg4.centos.org
 * updates: centosg4.centos.org
Setting up Install Process
Package kernel-2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

---

```
# yum install kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosr3.centos.org
 * extras: centosg4.centos.org
 * updates: centosg4.centos.org
Setting up Install Process
Package kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

---

```
#uname -r
2.6.32-042stab057.1
#uname -a
Linux asteriskserver 2.6.32-042stab057.1 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 02:17:07 MSD 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

As you can see is still running an old revision of 2.6.32 kernel, while yum says that i've another version installed.
I rebooted the system, it's a vps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most VPS environments used in server virtualization, like openvz, the virtual servers have direct access to the host's kernel for performance, so you cannot update your kernel version because you are sharing the host's kernel with all of the other virtual machines on the host.

If this is not true in your case and your Hoster is not doing that, maybe something is wrong with your bootloader. In most cases, the boot loader installed is GRUB. Have a look at the [GRUB chapter in the CentOS-guide](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-grub.html).

Comment: Ah ok, i'm currently compiling dahdi source, and it says You do not appear to have the sources for the 2.6.32-042stab057.1 kernel installed
There is a way to install a custom version of kernel-devel?